# Does the Android OS have a default photo album?

Tags: android, android-image, android-photos

I am creating a photo selector and I want to know if there is a default album in the Android OS that exists in all Android phones. For example: "Camera" or "DCIM"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of these default libraries

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
```

or

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```